# Acess modules from different directory

Tags: python

I have the following file structure

```
python/
    A/
        a.py
        b.py
    B/
        c.py
```

So there are two folders A and B under the folder python and I want to import modules from a.py and b.py - import them in c.py ( B folder)

I wrote an `__init__.py` with `__all__=['modulename']` and placed it in folder `B`. Now in my `c.py` I import the modules using `import` statement. This however does not seem to work. Any thoughts on how I can achieve the import of the modules in above case?

Comment: What was the purpose of adding the `__init__.py` to folder B, and what is `'modulename'`? Turning B into a package shouldn't have any impact on what you are trying to do.

Comment: How are you running your code?

Comment: I am not able to refer the modules. I added __init__.py that had a mention of __all__=["some_module_i _need"]. i thought that by doing this I could import the modules automatically in folder B.

Comment: An `__init__.py` in folder B turns B into a package. The contents of the `__init__.py` can help define what the package looks like to external modules that are trying to import it. The `__all__` variable defines which elements within a module will get imported if another module calls `from B import *`. Neither of these things determine what can be imported in c.py. I'd say Burhad Khalid's answer might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add the full path for `python` to `PYTHONPATH` in your environment.
2. Add **empty** `__init__.py` file inside `A`.

Then in `c.py`:

```
from A.a import something
from A.b import something

# or

import A
A.a.something
A.b.something
```

Answer (score 1):

add an **empty** `__init__.py` file in folder A, then import the modules as you'll do usually:

```
from A import a
```

or

```
from A.a import *
```

Comment: you have to add your 'python' project folder (the one containing folders A and B) to your 'PYTHONPATH' as suggested by mr. Khalid in the other post, otherwise it won't work

Answer (score 0):

If you are running `python c.py` from 'B' folder then you should add `__init__.py` to your 'B' directory and use `python -m B.c` within 'python' folder and do your imports like `import A.b` or something.